# How to create setup for any exe?

Tags: c#

I have .NET exe, I want to create a setup for this and after any login or restart this exe should be called automatically.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Answer (score 7):

As you are deploying a .NET application, there are multiple ways in which you can approach this challenge.

There are many questions you have to consider when choosing an installer strategy. These include:

- How do I plan to distribute this software?
- Is the software supposed to be connected to the internet in any way?
- What users is the software targeted towards?
- Do these users have specific computer installations, such as all having .NET Framework already installed?
- How should I approach the problem of updates to the software?

After answering some of these questions, you can get a general idea of how you should distribute the software. Then, you need to consider the various installers, and [Wikipedia has a convenient list that compares them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software), which might help you.

Below are some examples of what might work for you:

- ClickOnce deployment built into Visual Studio - my current favorite way, as this is the most easiest for users and for developers because updates and interaction is extremely simple
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System), an open source scripting system for such installers. A great tutorial on packaging and checking for the .NET Framework with NSIS can be found here.
- InstallShield (from Macrovision) - a heavily used installer system, but this one is not free, unlike other solutions
- [DreamShield](http://dreamshield.developpez.com/) - I haven't tried this one,  but it appears to be a viable solution.
- [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (with Visual Studio plugin)

Deployment of applications is a very tough part of software development, especially in .NET, because how can we know, for example, whether the potential user already has the .NET Framework installed on their system or not? Or what version is installed? Thus, we must use tools like ClickOnce and NSIS to help.

To your question about how to start your application immediately at login, there are four ways to approach this:

- Add registry key to start at login/bootup - MSDN explains that very well [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924527.aspx) However, most installation systems allow you to automatically configure the registry key for bootup addition.
- Use the Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a "task", in other words, to create a task that runs at startup. There is a .NET library for that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx), I've used it in two of my applications that run on a specific schedule, it works great!
- Adding the path to your executable into the Startup folder located at `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`(that is for all users - for single users you can customize the username in that path). By the way, that location is in Windows XP, it may be different in other version of Windows.
- If your application is a Windows Service, you can already automatically start at bootup, through svchost! There is a simple service configuration that will allow you to accomplish this.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for the specific tasks described in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

By setup, I'm going to assume you mean the conventional installer. A good open source solution is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). If that does not work, [here](http://www.csharp411.com/net-installers/) is a more complete list.

As for having it start whenever the computer restarts/you login, that is platform specific (the installer can be platform specific if the program is). On windows, the installer needs to add a shortcut to your program in the folder

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

(that is the easy method, there are surely more complicated registry settings).

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20100618084223/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2006/08/03/86985.aspx) lists a few useful links to info about Setup and Deployment projects using Visual Studio.

You could also google with the keywords ".net deployment project".

Answer (score 0):

Although not .NET specific, you can try [InstallJammer](https://web.archive.org/web/20180203163336/http://installjammer.com:80/). Its open source and multiplatform.