# how to make a installer for .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

How to make an installer for windows .net?

Comment: Hey, i need a installer with trial capatibilities

Comment: I believe the trial logic is usually done inside the application, not the installer.

Comment: The Shareware Start Kit was quite slick.  Might be a bit hard to find these days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create setup for any exe ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264457/how-to-create-setup-for-any-exe)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio can generate rudimentary installers.  New Project ==> Other Project Types ==> Setup and Deployment

[Deploying Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I would use this http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page to create the installer. (though there may be more suitable options for a .NET app)

The trial capability requirement should be coded into your app with your own logic, otherwise it can probably be broken by a simple system-restore operation.